# Audio Streaming over Network

Tags: audio-streaming

I have to make a project on Audio Streaming over a network. It should have two parts- a server and a client application. It should not be web-based application. Can anyone suggest me which language should I use?

Comment: Language is irrelevant, but why do you want to reinvent the wheel?  Use SHOUTcast for this, if appropriate.  If you need a low-latency solution, there are plenty of others.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages would do I guess.

Whatever the language, two building blocks:

- Client-Server Streaming library (for example, [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation.html#examples) from JBoss )
- Client Audio Library (This [sample code](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/faq/mp3/MP3.java.html) shows you how to play an mp3 file in java with JMF)